# How to change a calculator's display textContent from '0' to another number

Tags: javascript

I want to change calcDisplay's textContent from '0' to a number when I click one of the buttons. When I click a button, there's nothing. I don't even get any error and I have no idea what to do. I was thinking about doing innerHTML. Maybe I should put the ifs inside a function and call it inside the event?

```js
const add = (a, b) => a + b;
const subtract = (a, b) => a - b;
const multiply = (a, b) => a * b;
const divide = (a, b) => a / b;

const previousOperandTextElement = document.querySelector('.previousOperand')
const currentOperandTextElement = document.querySelector('.currentOperand')
const calcDisplay = document.querySelector('.output').textContent = '0'


// Click events for every button on the calculator //
const buttonEquals = document.querySelector('.keyButtonEquals');
buttonEquals.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const action = buttonEquals.dataset.action;
  console.log(action)
});

const buttonClear = document.querySelector('.keyButtonClear');
buttonClear.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const action = buttonClear.dataset.action;
  console.log(action)
});
const deleteButton = document.querySelector('.keyButtonDelete')
deleteButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const action = deleteButton.dataset.action;
  
});

const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.keyButton').forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
   const action = button.dataset.action;
   const buttonContent = button.textContent;
   const displayedNum = calcDisplay.textContent;
   if (action) {
   if (displayedNum === "0") {
     calcDisplay.textContent = buttonContent;
   }
  }
  });
});


const buttonOperation = document.querySelectorAll('.keyButtonOperation').forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
   const action = button.dataset.action;

    console.log(action)
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Calculator</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles/style.css">
        <body>
          <div class="calcContainer">

            
            <div class="buttons">
              <div class="output">
                <div class="previousOperand"></div>
                <div class="currentOperand"></div>
              </div>
              <button class="keyButton" data-action = 7>7</button>
              <button class="keyButton" data-action = 8>8</button>
              <button class="keyButton" data-action = 9>9</button>
              <button class="keyButtonOperation" data-action = "SignChange" >+/-</button>
              <button class="keyButtonDelete" data-action = "DEL">DEL</button>

              <button class="keyButton" data-action = 4>4</button>
              <button class="keyButton" data-action = 5>5</button>
              <button class="keyButton" data-action = 6>6</button>
              <button class="keyButtonOperation" data-action="multiply">X</button>
              <button class="keyButtonOperation" data-action="divide">%</button>

              <button class="keyButton" data-action = 1>1</button>
              <button class="keyButton" data-action = 2>2</button>
              <button class="keyButton" data-action = 3>3</button>
              <button class="keyButtonOperation" data-action = "substract">-</button>
              <button class="keyButtonEquals" data-action = "=">=</button>

              <button class="keyButtonClear" data-action = "clear">C</button>
              <button class="keyButton" data-action = 0>0</button>
              <button class="keyButton" data-action = .>.</button>
              <button class="keyButtonOperation" data-action = "add">+</button>
            </div>
          </div>

            <script src="./scripts/script.js"></script>
        </body>
    </head>
</html>
```

Comment: try to quote all your HTML attributes, even if "the spec says I don't have to". It makes it so much easier for others (and yourself) to read what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

I had to move down textContent of .output because you can't do anything with this 'value' if it's there. That's why I had to do calcDisplay.textContent = 0; in new line and I edited buttons event and it's working. Ty for help from TOP discord.

```js
const add = (a, b) => a + b;
const subtract = (a, b) => a - b;
const multiply = (a, b) => a * b;
const divide = (a, b) => a / b;

const previousOperandTextElement = document.querySelector('.previousOperand')
const currentOperandTextElement = document.querySelector('.currentOperand')
const calcDisplay = document.querySelector('.output')
calcDisplay.textContent = 0;



// Click events for every button on the calculator //
const buttonEquals = document.querySelector('.keyButtonEquals');
buttonEquals.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const action = buttonEquals.dataset.action;
  console.log(action)
});

const buttonClear = document.querySelector('.keyButtonClear');
buttonClear.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const action = buttonClear.dataset.action;
  console.log(action)
});
const deleteButton = document.querySelector('.keyButtonDelete')
deleteButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const action = deleteButton.dataset.action;

});

const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.keyButton').forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const action = button.dataset.action;
    calcDisplay.textContent = action;



  });
  console.log(calcDisplay);
});



const buttonOperation = document.querySelectorAll('.keyButtonOperation').forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const action = button.dataset.action;

    console.log(action)
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's to do with your line where you set calcDisplay (line 8). As you are assigning to the variable the result of setting the text output of output to '0' rather than the result of the query selector. If you change it to two lines it should work.

Also your head element in the HTML is wrapping round the body

E.g.
Change to:

```js
const add = (a, b) => a + b;
const subtract = (a, b) => a - b;
const multiply = (a, b) => a * b;
const divide = (a, b) => a / b;

const previousOperandTextElement = document.querySelector('.previousOperand')
const currentOperandTextElement = document.querySelector('.currentOperand')
const calcDisplay = document.querySelector('.output');
calcDisplay.textContent = '0'


// Click events for every button on the calculator //
const buttonEquals = document.querySelector('.keyButtonEquals');
buttonEquals.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const action = buttonEquals.dataset.action;
  console.log(action)
});

const buttonClear = document.querySelector('.keyButtonClear');
buttonClear.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const action = buttonClear.dataset.action;
  console.log(action)
});
const deleteButton = document.querySelector('.keyButtonDelete')
deleteButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const action = deleteButton.dataset.action;

});

const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.keyButton').forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const action = button.dataset.action;
    const buttonContent = button.textContent;
    const displayedNum = calcDisplay.textContent;

    if (action) {
      if (displayedNum === "0") {
        calcDisplay.textContent = buttonContent;
      }
    }
  });
});


const buttonOperation = document.querySelectorAll('.keyButtonOperation').forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const action = button.dataset.action;

    console.log(action)
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Calculator</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles/style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="calcContainer">
    <div class="buttons">
      <div class="output">
        <div class="previousOperand"></div>
        <div class="currentOperand"></div>
      </div>
      <button class="keyButton" data-action=7>7</button>
      <button class="keyButton" data-action=8>8</button>
      <button class="keyButton" data-action=9>9</button>
      <button class="keyButtonOperation" data-action="SignChange">+/-</button>
      <button class="keyButtonDelete" data-action="DEL">DEL</button>

      <button class="keyButton" data-action=4>4</button>
      <button class="keyButton" data-action=5>5</button>
      <button class="keyButton" data-action=6>6</button>
      <button class="keyButtonOperation" data-action="multiply">X</button>
      <button class="keyButtonOperation" data-action="divide">%</button>

      <button class="keyButton" data-action=1>1</button>
      <button class="keyButton" data-action=2>2</button>
      <button class="keyButton" data-action=3>3</button>
      <button class="keyButtonOperation" data-action="substract">-</button>
      <button class="keyButtonEquals" data-action="=">=</button>

      <button class="keyButtonClear" data-action="clear">C</button>
      <button class="keyButton" data-action=0>0</button>
      <button class="keyButton" data-action=.>.</button>
      <button class="keyButtonOperation" data-action="add">+</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="./scripts/script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```